# In Revenge of the Sith, why didn't Obi-Wan and Yoda gang up on the Emperor?

Tags: star-wars

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Yoda and Obi-Wan split up to confront Palpatine and Skywalker in single-combat. However, with the millions of lives at stake, and the obvious power of the Emperor with his immense skill in the force, and the massive armies at his disposal, wouldn't it have been better and safer to confront Palpatine together? With Anakin on a mission to Mustafar, he wouldn't be around to help Palpatine, and can be dealt with later.

This is especially so given that Mace Windu, widely regarded [as *the best* swordsman of the era](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mace_Windu), whose [Vaapad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII%3a_Juyo_/_Vaapad) fighting style draws on the Darkness of the opponent and becomes even more effective against a Sith, attempted Palpatine's arrrest with two other accomplished Jedi Masters.

Yoda and Obi-Wan are also affiliated with the light side of the force and shouldn't be as susceptible to raw emotions like pride. In this sense, Palpatine appears surprisingly accurate when he tells Yoda that ["Your arrogance blinds you"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3k0cE5Vwfk).

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: Hmm I don't know, Yoda held his own pretty well.

Comment: Obi-wan didn't seem terribly useful in group fights. In Ep1 he gets left behind and watches his master get killed. In Ep2 he fails to protect Anakin and is overwhelmed. And in Ep3 he gets knocked out in the first round. Yoda was probably just trying to spare him any more humiliation.

Comment: I don't know if there will be a satisfactory answer, since it is probably "Lucas did it" - but it really is a good question.  Isn't taking out a newly found Sith Lord top priority?  And it isn't like the Jedi are unaccustomed to teaming up against an opponent - they do it all the time.  Had Obi-Wan been there, the Empire might have been stopped before it got started.

Comment: One more thing to consider is that Palpatine was able to sense that Anakin was in danger even when Anakin was all the way on Mustafar. Had they taken Anakin out together first, Palpatine would have sensed it, and better protected himself. Had they taken out Palpatine first, it's possible that the extremely force sensitive Anakin would have sensed it and better protected himself. Taking them out simultaneously meant keeping the element of surprise in both encounters.

Comment: But they didn't confront them at the same time precisely - Palpatine gets to Anakin's burned body fast enough to save him with the Vader suit.  It had to take time to get to Mustafar.

Comment: As you mention the pride part in your question: My impression on that part was the jedi in part 1-3 came over quite arrogant in terms of their skills and their abilities AND their rules which ultimatively led to their downfall.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This was Yoda's decision. He tells Obi-Wan to go after Vader instead of accompanying him to confront the Emperor. Then he says, "To question, no time there is," cutting short any further discussion.

We don't know exactly what Yoda's reasoning was. But logically it must have been some combination of the following:

1. He believes Obi-Wan would be a liability in a fight with Darth Sidious. Yoda would have to expend energy and attention protecting Obi-Wan instead of pressing the attack. Obi-Wan would provide some additional help, but perhaps not enough to offset this disadvantage. If Yoda had viewed more of the security tapes (off-camera), he would have seen that Mace Windu's companions were no help whatsoever.
2. He is overconfident in his abilities. For example, he easily defeated Dooku, who in turn had easily beaten Obi-Wan and Anakin. Again, the security tapes recorded that Mace Windu actually had Palpatine at his mercy before Anakin turned up. Therefore, Yoda might have thought Sidious was vulnerable without Vader's help.
3. He is in a hurry to defeat both Sidious and Vader. They know from the attack on the Jedi Temple that Vader has command of Imperial forces. Yoda may be concerned that unless they kill Vader quickly, he will simply take over as ruler of the Empire. At that point, Vader would be surrounded by bodyguards and much more difficult for Obi-Wan and/or Yoda to defeat. Also, Vader has only just begun to embrace the power of the Dark Side; as time goes on, he will become much stronger.

Comment: (3) Is an excellent point

Comment: @TwilightSparkle: Thanks. Edited to emphasise that Anakin/Vader will grow stronger with time.

Comment: This is a great answer. My initial answer to this question was the same as your first point. But your third point, that Anakin, the Chosen One, will one day surpass Sidious and become an even greater threat is probably the best reason to go after him immediately.

Comment: (2) Is an interesting discussion. Mace Windu was the best swordsman of his era. It is entirely possible that he beat Palpatine squarely in a duel. It's also possible, and likely, that Palpatine sensed Anakin's arrival, and allowed himself to appear to be at Windu's mercy. Regardless, from the perspective of the security tapes, it would have appeared that Windu had won the duel.

Comment: @crush It was prudent for Palpatine to lose the duel in order to make Anakin snap and discredit the Jedi for attempted murder. Had they fought earnestly, who knows the result? Superior swordplay is only one component when Jedi fight.

Comment: To expand on (1), even if Obi-Wan doesn't need protecting, he'd still be a liability because Yoda would have to make sure his own attacks don't hurt his ally. Fighting alone is very different from fighting in a team.

Comment: @crush I'd say Palpatine purposefuly continued to hurt himself during the "fight" (by the time he already long lost) to make Anakin snap, rather than faking the whole fight. This is evidenced by the fact that unlike Yoda (in both his encounter with Dooku and Palpatine), he didn't appear to be exhausted by the dark-side force attacks thrown at him at all (while Yoda had to exert himself in both encounters). And since its widely believed that Yoda was far stronger in the force, it might point to Windu simply being "the" guy against the dark-side (as explained in EU).

Comment: @Luaan impossible to know for sure. Windy could have legitimately won, and Anakin showed up at the opportune time for the emperor to take advantage of his arrival. Windu was also a very powerful force user, had some training in the dark side, and his Vaapad fighting style only got stronger against dark force wielding opponents. On top of this, he possessed a unique ability called Shatterpoint that aided him greatly in solo encounters. Was he stronger than Yoda? Unlikely. But he might've been better suited to fight the emperor than Yoda.

Comment: 2 Brings up an interesting point - Yoda took on Dooku single-handedly, where Anakin and Obi-Wan were swept under the table by him.  He can't have thought very much of Obi-Wan's fighting prowess after that.

Answer (score 26):

It was a judgement call made by Yoda. Yoda doesn't believe Obi-Wan is strong enough to battle Palpatine.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html):

> OBI-WAN switches off the hologram. The TWO JEDI stand in silence for a few moments.
>
> YODA: Destroy the Sith, we must.
>
> OBI-WAN: Send me to kill the Emperor. I will not kill Anakin.
>
> YODA: To fight this Lord Sidious, strong enough, you are not.
>
> OBI-WAN: He is like my brother ... I cannot do it.
>
> YODA: Twisted by the dark side, young Skywalker has become. The boy you trained, gone he is . . . Consumed by Darth Vader.
>
> OBI-WAN: How could it have come to this?
>
> YODA: To question, no time there is.
>
> OBI-WAN: I do not know where the Emperor has sent him. I don't know where to look.
>
> YODA: Use your feelings, Obi-Wan, and find him, you will. Visit the new Emperor, my task is. May the Force be with you.
>
> OBI-WAN: May the Force be with you, Master Yoda.

As to exactly *why* Yoda decided this, Palpatine has already personally taken out three powerful Jedi - including the one regarded as their best swordsman.

At this point in G-Canon, Yoda and Obi-Wan are the only two confirmed surviving Jedi.

Knowing that Palpatine and Anakin were both risks that needed to be addressed, it makes a certain amount of sense to split up. In Yoda's estimation, Obi-Wan stood a chance against Anakin - so with a bit of <del>luck</del> The Force, at least one of their enemies would be defeated.

Obi-Wan may have disagreed, but Yoda already shut down further discussions saying,

> "To question, no time there is."

(Granted, he was replying to Obi-Wan's questioning of how this all came to be, but the point is valid for either question.)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Obi-Wan asks to confront the Emperor *alone*, and Yoda tells him he is not strong enough to do so. They don't discuss the possibility that they could *both* attack the Emperor before dealing with Anakin/Vader.

Comment: It does and it doesn't answer it. They don't discuss it because Yoda states that Obi-Wan isn't strong enough, and Obi-Wan defers to his judgement. Why don't they discuss it further? There's no real solid G-Canon reason other than "because Yoda said so". Yoda also says there's no time to talk about anything further. Lacking any further definitive reason, this is the closest thing to a G-Canon "reason" that appears to exist.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit If they both went after Sidious, I would imagine that Sidious would be able to blitz Kenobi just like he did with Windu's strike team.

Comment: "But Master Yoda, if we go together-" "Remember what happened LAST time Yoda had to bail you out of battle you could not win, you will." "...Ah, point taken."

Comment: Yoda should just have shot the bastard, no messing around, just kill the enemy

Comment: An interesting thought: had Obi-Wan not stowed aboard Padme's ship, she would've died, and Luke and Leia would never have existed.

Comment: @crush, if Obi-Wan had not stowed aboard Padme's ship, Anakin may not have ever gotten pissed off at her enough to Force-Choke her in the first place.

Comment: @phantom42 That's true. He didn't force choke her until Obi-Wan emerged from the vessel. However, she was already heart-broken and under immense duress seeing that Anakin had turned to the Dark side, and having learned of the terrible deeds he had taken part. It's possible that she had lost the will to live at that instant, but you're right. We can't know for sure. Good counterpoint.

Comment: @phantom42 then Luke and Leia would have grown up as Sith Younglings. Don't think that is how A New Hope went.

Answer (score 9):

Matthew Stover's "*Revenge of the Sith*" novelization goes into a little more detail than the movie script:

> *{{Yoda, addressing "why did Anakin choose the Dark side}}*
>   “Why? Why matters not. There is no why. There is only a Lord of the Sith, and his apprentice. Two Sith.” Yoda leaned close. “And two Jedi.”
>
> Obi-Wan nodded, but he still couldn’t meet the gaze of the ancient Master. “I’ll take Palpatine.”
>
> “Strong enough to face Lord Sidious, you will never be. Die you will, and painfully.”
>
> “Don’t make me kill Anakin,” he said. “He’s like my brother, Master.”
>
> “The boy you trained, gone he is—twisted by the dark side. Consumed by Darth Vader. Out of this misery, you must put him. To visit our new Emperor, my job will be.”
>
> Now Obi-Wan did face him. “Palpatine faced Mace and Agen and Kit and Saesee—four of the greatest swordsmen our Order has ever produced. By himself. **Even both of us together wouldn’t have a chance**.”
>
> **“True,”** Yoda said. “**But both of us apart, a chance we might create** …”

So, Yoda very deliberately decided that there was no point in them facing the Emperor together (Obi-Wan voiced it, and Yoda agreed). But somehow, he saw - correctly, as we later found out - that separately they would set off a chance that would eventually free the Galaxy of the Sith.

He was correct both tactically and strategically:

- Tactically, the threat from Obi-Wan to Vader caused Sidious to abandon the fight in the Senate Chamber when he may have finished off Yoda; and with him, the important realization of how to train New Model Jedi.
- Strategically, Vader and Luke turned out how they did, and Anakin in the end did fulfill the Prophecy.

Answer (score 8):

Some fight better solo. They can move, attack and dodge at speed without tripping over their 'partner'. Have you ever played doubles in table tennis? If your partner isn't adept at where to be when he's suppose to be there, he's more of a hindrance than a help. Yoda would know this about Obi-Wan's current lack in skill/ability level. Yoda obviously decided he had a better chance taking on Sidious alone and without Obi-Wan underfoot.

Comment: You could take two great solo tennis players, and pair them up in a doubles match, and they might easily be beaten by a duet of tennis players who regularly plays doubles. This is a valid point, though I think it mostly would've been Yoda having to hold back to protect Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 2):

Yoda, in the Clone Wars cartoon had a vision , in season 6 I think, he was fighting the emperor with Anakin, and he lost the fight because he had to save his fighting partner. Maybe this is some of the reason.

Comment: No one has an opinion on this? Not even a downvote?